# Pulling All User Data in Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this future builder that pulls the info of every user into some variables, then I create a widget with those variables for each user, and finally save each card in a widget list.

But I would like to change this into a function that does the same but doesn't return anything, so that I can put it in a initState(), and just use the list of widgets.

Here's what I have:

```
List<Widget> userCards = [];
...
cardBuilder: (context, index) => 
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  future: _firestore.collection('users').getDocuments(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {...}
    final users = snapshot.data.documents;
    for (var user in users) {
      _name = user.data['name'];
      _email = user.data['email'];
      _age = user.data['age'];
      final userCard = Card(...);
      userCards.add(userCard);
    }
    return userCards[index];
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
void getData() async{
 Firestore.instance.collection('users').getDocuments().then((value){
    value.documents.forEach((doc){
       print(doc.data);
      _name = doc.data['name'];
      _email = doc.data['email'];
      _age = doc.data['age'];
      final userCard = Card(...);
      userCards.add(userCard);
    });
  });
```

Comment: The **user.___** was part of the loop, but I took that out and it worked perfectly. Thank you!